# Converting async method to events

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, task

1. I have a library written almost exclusively using Tasks and the async/await pattern. (Cancellation Tokens, IProgress, the whole 9 yards)
2. What I want is to wrap these existing static async methods with a generic EAP pattern.
3. I have come up with a solution, but would like to bounce it off someone else to see if it even makes sense.

In .Net there are a ton of pages out there on how to wrap an EAP pattern in a Tasks, but not for going the other direction.  Nevermind the why, I know wanting to do this probably sounds crazy, but if the library is being consumed by someone unused to async/await and Tasks.  I've come up with a class that wraps the Task with an event pattern, in the InitEvents() method I wire up events for *Cancelled*, *ProgressChanged*, and *Finished* events to the task internals.

```
public class PackageOperation
{
    public static PackageOperation GetPackageOperation<T>( T arg1, 
            Func<T, CancellationToken, Progress<ProcessedBoardArgs>, Task<IPackage>> func )
    {
        var progress = new Progress<ProcessedBoardArgs>();
        var cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Task<IPackage> packageTask = new Task<IPackage>(() =>
        {
            var inner = func(arg1, cancelTokenSource.Token, progress);
            inner.Wait();
            return inner.Result;
        }, cancelTokenSource.Token);

        var packageOperation = new  PackageOperation();
        packageOperation._packageTask = packageTask;
        packageOperation._progress = progress;
        packageOperation._cancelTokenSource = cancelTokenSource;
        packageOperation.InitEvents();

        return packageOperation;
    }

    private PackageOperation() { }

    public PackageOperationProgressHandler ProgressChanged;
    public PackageOperationCancelledHandler Cancelled;
    public PackageOperationFinishedHandler Finished;
}
```

And here's how it is used:

```
    public static PackageOperation GetPackage( PackageDescriptor pd )
    {
        return PackageOperation.GetPackageOperation<PackageDescriptor>(pd, GetPackageAsync);
    }

    private static async Task<IPackage> GetPackageAsync( PackageDescriptor pd, 
            CancellationToken token, IProgress<ProcessedBoardArgs> progress )
    {
        return await PackageParser.ParsePackage(pd.PackagePath, token, progress);
    }
```

So, besides the obvious issue of moving backward from Tasks to EAP patterns, will this work?  Is there anything glaringly wrong with it?

Comment: Could you please clarify what kind of help you are looking for? Clearly you already tried converting several APIs and integrated into several event-based apps. Did you find any problems/Deadlocks/Exceptions? (If you did not try  - this  is exactly what is "glaringly wrong with it").

Comment: Probably be a better question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Good points, thanks.  Yes, it does just fine in unit tests, I just felt like I was violating some sort of unwritten coding convention.  Nothing obviously wrong with it.  Stephen, next time I will post to Code Review, didn't even know that branch of StackExchange existed, thanks.